# Maintained local concentration of suspended particulates

Tags: electrostatics, gas

Is it possible for suspended particulates to maintain gradient or aggregate into stable clouds due to some interactions between individual particles, or interactions with surrounding gas molecules?

Perhaps, some kind of charged dust might exhibit weak attractive forces between individual particles, and thus tend to congregate - not strong enough to lump together, but enough not to dissipate around too much.

Also, perhaps it might work in presence of an external magnetic: i.e., a stable cloud of particulates could aggregate around a source of such field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the particles are small enough, they are colloidal.  Such particles do what you are inquiring about, as they do not settle out of the solution.  Common examples are cigarette smoke in air, and extremely small spherical globules in milk.